# Two Django projects conflicting with one another

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have two separate Django projects, one at / and the other at /foo.  Intermittently, if I attempt to access the project at /, it will raise a PageNotFound exception and show the URL file from the /foo project, and vice versa.  I'm assuming there's some sort of conflict with Apache or mod_wsgi, but I can't really find what it is.  Is there a way to avoid this?  I don't really want to run each project on a separate domain, which seems to work.

**EDIT**:  My django/wsgi configuration (my httpd.conf is basically unchanged from install)

```
    WSGIPythonPath /var/django/bumppoman:/var/django/roads:/var/django/hawthorn:/var/django/wiffleball
    <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName site1.com

    WSGIScriptAlias /hawthorn /var/django/hawthorn/apache-files/wsgi.py
    WSGIScriptAlias /roads /var/django/roads/apache/wsgi.py
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/bumppoman/apache/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/var/django/roads/apache">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/django/bumppoman/apache">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/django/hawthorn/apache-files">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName site2.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/wiffleball/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory "/var/django/wiffleball/apache">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Django do not work well in subdirs, so use subdomains. Or add your subdir to `urls` of the second project and show us the apache config for it.

Comment: @ilvar rubbish. Django's perfectly comfortable in subdirectories, as long as you configure it properly. Brendon, please show your Apache and mod_wsgi configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the relevant configuration.

Comment: I gave up and switched to subdomains because it was too frustrating.  I'd still be interested in seeing a solution, however.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I coldn't find a way to make a Django project easily installable in subdirs without hardcoding it into `urls` and fiddling with webserver setup. I haven't said it's impossible but there are some issues.